# No IE o código funciona e no Chrome não

Tags: javascript

Tenho essa função:

```
function AbreGrupoCarencia(pTitulo, pTipo, pLinha, pCodigo, pCodTsContrato, pCodEntidadeTS, pNomeEntidade, pProtocoloAtendimento, pCodContratoAmpliado)
{
    var txt_codigo = eval('document.form01.' + pCodigo + '.value');

    //alert(txt_codigo);

    if ( txt_codigo != '' ){
        if ( parseInt(txt_codigo) <=0)
            alert('Código inválido');
    }
    if ( txt_codigo == '' ){
        alert('Código não informado');
        return false;
    }
    var sAction = '../../cmp/asp/cmp0102a.asp';

    sAction = sAction + '?cod_pesquisa=' + txt_codigo;
    sAction = sAction + '&ind_tipo=' + pTipo;
    sAction = sAction + '&cod_ts_contrato=' + pCodTsContrato;   
    sAction = sAction + '&cod_entidade_ts=' + pCodEntidadeTS;
    sAction = sAction + '&nome_entidade=' + pNomeEntidade;
    sAction = sAction + '&txt_protocolo_atendimento=' + pProtocoloAtendimento;
    sAction = sAction + '&cod_contrato_ampliado=' + pCodContratoAmpliado;                 
    sAction = sAction + '&PT=' + pTitulo;

    AbrePesquisaCrossBrowser(sAction, pTitulo, pTitulo, 1000, 800, 50, 50, 'S');
}
```

O que se passa. Bem, o `alert` comentado no início da função, no `IE` me trás 10(em uma situação) e no `Chrome`, obedecendo os mesmos critérios, me trás `undefined`. O erro está nessa linha: `var txt_codigo = eval('document.form01.' + pCodigo + '.value');`. Varrendo o código, observei que o IE aceita o getElementByID() mesmo que não exista ID, somente Name, porem o Chrome não. Se é ID tem que ter ID(correto). Bem, na varredura, coloquei ID para todos os elementos que tem somente Name. Isso resolveu alguns problemas, mas continuo, nesse arquivo, não funcionando. Ele deveria exibir uma janela(popup) e nada acontece.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: E o porque do `eval` ? Você não pode ler o valor do elemento direto ?

Comment: Assim o site é enorme e não estamos aqui para fazer esse tipo de coisa. Caso o eval for o problema de não funcionar, aí intervimos, mas nossa função é fazer o site no chrome. É um site muito grande e nosso limite está aí. Porque o que tem de eval(), cara, é demais, mas se tá funcionando não intervimos. Por isso ele tá lá. Caso seja ele o motivo de não funcionar, coisa que eu não sei, aí sim, intervimos. Nós aqui só customizamos para o chrome. Descobrimos muitos erros, mas não podemos intervir. Isso gera custo, bem você sabe como é terceiros, Qualquer coisa, tem que ter aprovação dos de cima.

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi, vocês não podem alterar os scripts do site, é isso ?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown não, não foi isso. Podemos sim. O que eu disse é que o site é muito grande. Tem infinitos eval(), e não vamos nos ater a isso. Nossa função aqui é fazer funcionar no chrome o módulo em questão. Se o eval() tal for o problema, intervimos, alteramos e etc. Caso não, deixamos de lado e nos atemos à nossa função apenas. Não estamos corrigindo o site, apenas um módulo para funcionar no chrome, pois ele não roda no chrome dado a vários erros. Fomos chamados para isso apenas.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown por exemplo. Você citou o eval() na função. Se for ele o problema intervimos, se ele não for o problema, deixamos de lado e vamos ver o que está acontecendo que não funciona, mais adiante. Nesse caso, pode ser ele o problema, postei para pedir a opinião dos colegas a respeito.

Comment: Eu perguntei do eval pra tentar descobrir se o erro é nele mesmo, já que até você disso que o erro está na linha dele, e é claro que se tiver errado você tem que mexer, se não, não.

Comment: Apesar do eval ser totalmente desnecessário eu não acho que ele seja a causa do problema. Você já conferiu o valor do `pCodigo` está correto? Pois testando aqui no Chrome, IE e Firefox em todos esta forma de acessar o valor de um campo funcionou.

Comment: @LeandroGodoyRosa também acho. Mas o AP é meio ignorante nos comentários então tá difícil ajudar.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown, não entendi o AP ignorante nos comentários. O que foi que eu falei demais aí? Realmente não entendi. Fiz três comentários tentando expor minha situação e dá o maior número de subsídio possível, e não vi onde eu escrevi algo grosseiro a qualquer um aqui. Não entendi o seu comentário. Aqui deveria ter apenas comentário relacionado ao cerne da questão. Essas coisas deveria estar no META, mas não fui em nenhum momento grosseiro. Pode me mostrar qual linha? Se houve um entendimento errado, eu corrijo, mas leiam meus comentários e vejam se procede o cementário do Down.

Comment: @pnet não quis dizer grosseiro, mas não ajudou muito em seus comentários, só isso. Eu ia falar a mesma coisa do Diego mas você ficou falando um monte de coisas.. enfim.

Comment: Não acho que eu impedi de você falar alguma coisa do Diego, mas a resposta dele resolveu meu problema. Vou me ater ao cerne do problema. Javascript. Esse tipo de comentário, por mim, encerra-se aqui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É o `eval()` o problema.

Troque por

`document.getElementsByName(pCodigo)[0].value`